# Calculate day difference between two specific records which are in sequence

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table which has sets of records that follow a sequence of events. I would like to find out cycle time (time it took to complete) by calculating the difference between few specific set of records.

Table "**project_cycle_time**":

| PROJECT_TYPE | ST_PROJECT_ID | main_activity | sub_activity | overall_seq | section_seq | ACTUALDATE | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'AA' | 'AAA' | 1 | 1 | '01-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'AA' | 'AAB' | 1 | 2 | '02-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'AA' | 'AAC' | 1 | 3 | '03-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'AA' | 'AAD' | 1 | 4 | '04-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'BB' | 'BBA' | 2 | 1 | '04-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'BB' | 'BBB' | 2 | 2 | '05-01-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'BB' | 'BBC' | 2 | 3 | '06-03-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'CC' | 'CCA' | 3 | 1 | '06-03-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'CC' | 'CCB' | 3 | 2 | '07-03-2021' | 'complete' |
| 'A_NEW_PRJ' | 1111 | 'CC' | 'CCC' | 3 | 3 | '08-03-2021' | 'incomplete' |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |

The above table has a large set of project_id's belonging to different project types.

I would like to obtain cycletime-time it took to complete the main activity in number of days. Expected sample out is as below,

| ProjectID | main_acitvity | cycletime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | AA | 90 days |
| 1111 | BB | 62 days |
| 1111 | CC | null |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

The first main activity (AA) would be difference in dates between sequence.subsequence 1.1 and 1.4.

The subsequent activity (BB) difference should be between previous main activity's last sub activity and last sub activity of current main activity. In this case difference between 1.4 and 2.3

Some of the project_id status may have been marked as incomplete (like CC), these main_activity which is a difference between 2.3 and 3.3 should yield null.

Some of the conditions to handle are

1. if Overall_seq 1 and section_seq 4 record is missing then it must consider section_seq 3 provided section_seq 3 is complete. If section_seq 3 is missing then consider section_seq 2 provided section_seq 2 is complete.
2. If overall_seq 1 is not complete and section_seq 4 record is complete then diff of date should be null.
3. if overall_seq 1 is complete and section_seq 4 is incompelte then the diff of date should be null.

Is there a way to do this via SQL query in one go, I was planning to loop through the records and do it via java or sql cursor but that would take considerable amount of time as there are 1M+ records.

I did try below which sorta works but just for one main_activity only and also the sequences are fixed so this SQL does not handle all of the rules mentioned above.

```
select start.PROJECT_TYPE, start.ST_PROJECT_ID , (end.ACTUALDATE - start.ACTUALDATE) as diff
from project_cycle_time start join
     project_cycle_time end
     on start.PROJECT_TYPE='A_NEW_PRJ' and
       
        start.status = 'Completed' and
      
        start.PROJECT_TYPE = end.PROJECT_TYPE and
        start.ST_PROJECT_ID = end.ST_PROJECT_ID and
        start.status = end.status and
        
( (start.overall_seq = 1 and start.section_seq=1 and end.overall_seq=1 and end.section_seq=4)   -- check between 1.1 and 1.4
)   order by start.st_project_id , start.overall_seq, start.section_seq asc ;
```

If I include below two it has no effect for some reason.  Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction to go about this.

```
(start.overall_seq = 1 and start.section_seq=4 and end.overall_seq=2 and end.section_seq=3)  OR  -- check between 1.4 and 2.3 for BB cycle time
(start.overall_seq = 1 and start.section_seq=4 and end.overall_seq=2 and end.section_seq=3)   -- check between 2.3 and 3.3 for CC cycle time
```

##############################
Update:(06/05/2023)

One of the conditions that I would like the SQL to handle (if it does not have performance impact) is to not consider the first and last record of a main sequence to calculate cycle time unless it is the first main sequence. Let me explain with this below example:

Table "**project_cycle_time**":

| main_activity | overall_seq | section_seq | ACTUALDATE | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'AA' | 1 | 1 | '01-01-2021' |  |
| 'AA' | 1 | 2 | '02-01-2021' |  |
| 'AA' | 1 | 3 | '03-01-2021' |  |
| 'AA' | 1 | 4 | '04-01-2021' | Cycle time for Main activity AA is days between sequence 1-1 and 1-4 which is 90 days |
| 'BB' | 2 | 1 | '05-01-2021' |  |
| 'BB' | 2 | 2 | '05-01-2021' |  |
| 'BB' | 2 | 3 | '06-03-2021' | Cycle time for activity BB is days between 2-3 and 1-4 which is 62 days |
| 'CC' | 3 | 1 | '07-03-2021' |  |
| 'CC' | 3 | 2 | '07-03-2021' |  |
| 'CC' | 3 | 3 | '07-03-2021' | Cycle time for activity CC is days between 3-3 and 2-3 (but this is incomplete so it would be 0) |

Note:  Using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: It is possible, but messy, to do the task using a "self join" into a "temporary" table with a new "auto_increment" to let you compare one row to the next/previous by using that auto_inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql 8, we can use window functions to get the desired output :

`row_number()` was used to provide a unique ids per main_activity descendently.

`lag(ACTUALDATE)` was used to get the previous ACTUALDATE for each row.

`first_value` and `last_value` used to obtain the first and latest status per main_activity.

Then in cte2 the `min(previous_ACTUALDATE)` returns the previous main activity's last sub activity (exemple activity 2 would be 1.4)

Finaly, the cycletime would be the difference between the ACTUALDATE and min_ACTUALDATE, but only if status are both complete.

```
with cte as (
  select PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity, ACTUALDATE,
          row_number() over (partition by PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity order by section_seq desc) as rn,
          lag(ACTUALDATE) over (partition by PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID order by ACTUALDATE) as previous_ACTUALDATE,
          first_value(status) over (partition by PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity order by section_seq) AS first_status,
          last_value(status) over (partition by PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity order by section_seq) AS last_status
  from project_cycle_time
),
cte2 as (
  select *, min(previous_ACTUALDATE) over (partition by PROJECT_TYPE, ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity) as min_ACTUALDATE
  from cte
)
select ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity,
       case when first_status = 'complete' and last_status = 'complete' 
            then  datediff(ACTUALDATE, min_ACTUALDATE)
       end as cycletime
from cte2
where rn = 1
```

Result :

```
PROJECT_TYPE    ST_PROJECT_ID   main_activity   cycletime
A_NEW_PRJ       1111            AA              90
A_NEW_PRJ       1111            BB              63
A_NEW_PRJ       1111            CC              0
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xG_PH5tY)

Comment: Hi @SelVazi, thank you for the solution but there is one condition that the sql does not handle. When overall_seq  is 1 then it should consider difference of date between 1.4 & 1.1, that is max and min of that but for subsequent sequences it should consider the last sequence of previous overall_seq and last seq of current overall_seq.
i.e:
(overall_seq => difference between)
(1 => 1.4 - 1.1 )
(2 => 2.3 - 1.4)
(3 => 3.3 - 2.3)
(5 => 5.7 - 3.3)
.    If overall_seq 4 is missing (above) it needs to consider previous record last entry

Comment: Are you using mysql 8 ?

Comment: This is on Mysql 5. 7 . I have updated the corner case in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the cycle time for each main activity in terms of the number of days it took to complete, you can use a SQL query with grouping and date calculations. Here's an example query based on your table structure:

```
SELECT
  ST_PROJECT_ID AS ProjectID,
  main_activity AS main_activity,
  DATEDIFF(
    MAX(CASE WHEN overall_seq = section_seq THEN ACTUALDATE END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN overall_seq = 1 THEN ACTUALDATE END)
  ) AS cycletime
FROM project_cycle_time
WHERE status = 'complete'
GROUP BY ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store dates as string type. Store them as `DATE`, because MySQL helps you a lot when it comes to query building. As a consequence, the first forced step is to transform your string, having "month-day-year" format into MySQL standard format ("day-month-year") using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

Your three stated conditions can be summarized with the fact that the boundary status shall not be incomplete, that's what we're going to attempt to do here.

In MySQL 8.0 you can approach this problem with window functions, first computing the following values:

- max date, with `MAX`, partition by project_id and main_activity
- min date, with `MIN`, partition by project_id and main_activity
- first status, with `FIRST_VALUE`, partition by project_id and main_activity, order by section_seq
- last status, with `FIRST_VALUE`, partition by project_id and main_activity, order by section_seq descendently

Once you've done it, you can directly compute the difference in dates between max and min date, but only when the boundary status values are both not incomplete.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           ST_PROJECT_ID, 
           main_activity,
           MIN(STR_TO_DATE(ACTUALDATE, '%m-%d-%Y')) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity ) AS mindate,
           MAX(STR_TO_DATE(ACTUALDATE, '%m-%d-%Y')) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity ) AS maxdate,
           FIRST_VALUE(status_) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity
               ORDER     BY section_seq                  ) AS first_status,
           FIRST_VALUE(status_) OVER(
               PARTITION BY ST_PROJECT_ID, main_activity
               ORDER     BY section_seq DESC             ) AS last_status
    FROM tab
)
SELECT ST_PROJECT_ID,
       main_activity,
       CASE WHEN first_status = 'complete' AND last_status = 'complete' 
            THEN DATEDIFF(maxdate, mindate)
       END AS cycletime
FROM cte
```

This allows you to aggregate once only, with some gain in performance.

**Output**:

| ST_PROJECT_ID | main_activity | cycletime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | AA | 90 |
| 1111 | BB | 63 |
| 1111 | CC | null |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9TZX4pVcCVP1cVsnuzop6/2).

Comment: HI @lemon, thank you for the response. Yes I am storing the date fields as date time, just that they are represented as string in my question.  Your SQL works smiliar to SelVazi's response but is it possible to have the difference of dates calculated as per rule  (overall_seq => difference between) (1 => 1.4 - 1.1 ) (2 => 2.3 - 1.4) (3 => 3.3 - 2.3) (5 => 5.7 - 3.3) . If overall_seq 4 is missing it needs to consider previous record last entry

Comment: Update sample data and expected ouput inside your post with corner cases. It's unclear understanding your requirement from a description.

Comment: I have updated the question with a dataset table with comments explaining the corner case, which is nice to have not necessary.

Comment: I guess this solution is not going to help you specifically as long as you're using mysql 5.7. Although apart from that, it still doesn't look clear to me, maybe other people can understand your requirement better.